# not able to fetch value from controller to view in spring from pojos

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following code as

**controller**

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

     @RequestMapping("/products")
    public String list(Model model) {
        Product iphone = new Product("P1233", "iPhone 5s", new BigDecimal(500));
        iphone.setDescription("pple iPhone 5s smartphone with 4.00-inch 640x1136 display and 8-megapixel rear camera");
        iphone.setCategory("smart phone");
        iphone.setManfactuer("Apple");
        iphone.setUnitsInStock(1000);
        model.addAttribute("product", iphone);
        return "products";

    }
```

**product**

```
private String productId;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
    private String description;
    private String manfactuer;
    private String category;
    private long unitsInStock;
    private long uintsInOrder;
    private boolean discountinued;
//getter and setter
```

now when I try to fetch value in jsp as:

```
   <h3>${product.name}</h3>
   <p>${product.description}</p>
   <p>${product.unitPrice}USD</p>
   <p>Available ${product.unitsInStock} units in stock</p>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

not getting any output in browser but when I change mapping to **/** instead of **/products** and `loadOnStartUp` to 1 for dispatcher servlet, everything is fine.
Is there any way to get values without mapping directly to `dispatcherServlet` as if I have more `@controller` classes then IDK, how to manage this?

**EDIT**

I have two controllers one is

```
@RequestMapping("/")
   public String welcome(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", "Greetings of the day");
    model.addAttribute("tagline", "this is the tagline");
    return "welcome";
}
```

working fine and when i use this configuration not getting output in browser but when I change to

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String list(Model model) {
        Product iphone = new Product("P1233", "iPhone 5s", new BigDecimal(500));
        iphone.setDescription("pple iPhone 5s smartphone with 4.00-inch 640x1136 display and 8-megapixel rear camera");
        iphone.setCategory("smart phone");
        iphone.setManfactuer("Apple");
        iphone.setUnitsInStock(1000);
        model.addAttribute("product", iphone);
        return "products";

    }
```

giving me output , but I want to use `@RequestMapping("/products)` , How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have configured ViewResolver?

For example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Products page is `products.jsp` file?

Answer (score 0):

## 配置 web.xml

`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:spring/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

## 你需要配置注解扫描包路径，及对应的视图解析器

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.group.springmvc.controller" /> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>`

Comment: Please use English